# Distributing a jar for use in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I've built a jar that I can use from pyspark by adding it to `${SPARK_HOME}/jars` and calling it using

`spark._sc._jvm.com.mypackage.myclass.mymethod()`

however what I'd like to do is bundle that jar into a python wheel so someone can pip install a the jar into their running pyspark/jupyter session. I'm not very familiar with python packaging, is it possible to distribute jars inside a wheel and have that jar be automatically available to pyspark?

I want to put a jar inside a wheel or egg (not even sure if I can do that???) and upon installation of said wheel/egg, out that jar in a place where it will be available to the jvm.

I guess what I'm really asking is, how do I make it easy for someone to install a 3rd party jar and use it from pyspark?

Comment: Do you mean using how to use Java UDF funtions in pyspark?

Comment: No, nothing to do with UDFs

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned above, and hope you have already used the --jars  option and able to use function in pyspark. As understood your requirement correctly you want to add this jar in install package so that jar library will be available on each node of cluster.

There is one source found on databricks which talks about adding third party jar files pyspark python wheel install. See if that is only information you are looking at.

https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html#upload-a-jar-python-egg-or-python-wheel

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately doesn’t really help as it doesn’t talk about my specific use case. I want to put a jar inside a wheel or egg (not even sure I can do that???) and, upon installation of said wheel/egg, put that jar in a place where it will be available to the JVM.